# PSR-4 Autoloading in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, autoload, psr-4

Working on an application that will be used to extend the [Chatter](https://github.com/thedevdojo/chatter) package

Issue is, **I want to make modifications to the package but don't want to do is directly to the package. Changes won't persist after a `composer update`.**

Now from my understanding extending the package would require me to exclude the specific file from auto-loading and load my own files/directories...

**composer.json**

I made changes to composer.json to accommodate to Mac/Unix and Windows file path syntax:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "vendor/devdojo/chatter/src/Controllers/ChatterDiscussionController.php",
        "vendor/devdojo/chatter/src/Models/Discussion.php",
        "vendor\\devdojo\\chatter\\src\\Controllers\\ChatterDiscussionController.php",
        "vendor\\devdojo\\chatter\\src\\Models\\Discussion.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Forum\\": "app/forum"
    }
},
```

**folder structure**

```
.
+-- app
|   +-- Console
|   +-- Exceptions
|   +-- Forum
    |   +-- Chatter
        |   +-- Controllers
            |   +-- ChatterDiscussionController.php
        |   +-- Models
            |   +-- ...
|   +-- Helpers
|   +-- Http
|   +-- ...
+-- bootstrap
+-- ...
```

**Custom ChatterDiscussionController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Forum\Chatter\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use DevDojo\Chatter\Events\ChatterAfterNewDiscussion;
use DevDojo\Chatter\Events\ChatterBeforeNewDiscussion;
use DevDojo\Chatter\Models\Models;
use Event;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as Controller;
use Validator;
use App\User;

class ChatterDiscussionController extends Controller
{...
```

**test**

To test this, I placed `dd("Custom")` in my custom DiscussionController and `dd("Original")` within the package version of DiscussionController. And as you may already surmise, this continues to hit the package version of the DiscussionController.

The only way I got this to work was to add the specific file to files key within autoload section `"files": ["app/Helpers/Chatter.php"]` ***<~~ This is an example***. This will be a managing nightmare once I start extending more and more packages. From my understanding this can be accomplished by creating a ServiceProvider, but I am unable to find a suitable example of getting this to work using that method.

Has anyone had this issue before? What was the fix. Any help in the right direction is much appreciated.